# I have mockup usermanager in my test

Tags: c#

I have to create owin environment for my unit testing which is required to create a Usermanager object. In my current situation my usermanager is null because it is not getting owincontext.

Here is my code which access usermanger

```
public SLUser FindByName(string userName)
{
return UserManager.FindByName(userName);

}
```

Here is the code for setting usermanager

```
public SLUserManager UserManager
{
get
{
return _userManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<SLUserManager>();
}
set
{
_userManager = value;
}

}
```

the exception i am getting

```
System.InvalidOperationException was caught
HResult=-2146233079
Message=No owin.Environment item was found in the context.
Source=Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

I tried to create background thread which runs startup .configureauth() method which creates usermanager object and also create owien context.so that it can get owin context for my test method . is it a correct way to do it..??
suggestions reply will do

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but it sounds like the issue is that your test is trying to use a real implementation of SLUserManager. If you don't set this property then when you try to access it your code will try to create a local default (using this line of code)

```
return _userManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<SLUserManager>();
```

There is a way round this for your unit test, since your UserManager property has a public setter you might be able to create a mock SLUserManager and set this in your tests (avoiding having to use the local default)

```
    [Test]
    public void FindByName_WhenPassedUserName_ReturnsSLUserWithUserName()
    {
        var myClassBeingTested = "";//create an instance of the class being tested
        var mockSLUserManager = "";//create a mock version of SLUserManager 
        myClassBeingTested.UserManager = mockSLUserManager;
        var userName = "mark_h";
        var expected = mockSLUserManager.FindByName(userName);

        var result = myClassBeingTested.FindByName(userName);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
    }
```

The part that may be tricky is your mock SLUserManager, this is a class that you will be able to fully control in a test environment.

You should not test against an implementaiton of SLUserManager that is created for you by code that you have no control over. This would not be a unit test since you are no longer testing purely your "unit" of code.

In the example you provided what do you actually need to test? - You need to test that when "FindbyName" is called it delegates this call to UserManager and then returns the expected result. If your UserManager is broken and returns no SLUser or the wrong one then this is not a failure of the code you are trying to unit test.

To try to explain my point further, the code you provided is fairly simple and I'm presuming that you are confident that it is correct. It should therefore pass a unit test but isn't because "GetUserManager" is failing. You did not write the code that is failing, so you need to isolate it from your test and test only the code that you are writing.

If you are new to mocking I suggest you read a bit about it before going any further.

Comment: Hello, The solution you mentioned of assigning mock usermanager to my class usermanager didn't worked for me. Our project is using identitynanager.owiencontext so it is showing me the error :                                 Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<Superload.Mvc.Models.ApplicationUser>' to 'Bentley.Superload.Identity.SLUserManager' D:\rotation2\Superload\SuperloadSource\net\websites\eSuperload\superload\Superload.Mvc.Tests\Controllers\AdminControllerTest.cs 444 53 Superload.Mvc.Tests